# Lapis Lazuli ItemStack ID

Tags: java, minecraft

Currently I'm trying to make an autosmelt plugin and every time the player breaks the block, it reads the block broken and gives the block smelted to the player. Now, lapis lazuli may not need to be smelted in game, but since, when the block is broken, it cancels the block breaking and manually breaks it ***then*** gives the item, I need to do:

```
player.getInventory().addItem(new ItemStack(Material.LAPIS, 1));
player.updateInventory();
```

But as some of you may know, Material.LAPIS is not a bukkit/spigot Material. Meaning that I would need to do:

```
player.getInventory().addItem(new ItemStack(Material.INK_SACK, 1, (short) 4));
player.updateInventory();
```

Since lapis is technically a dye item. But of course this does not work for a reason I do not know. I am using the 1.10.2 spigot API so maybe it works in 1.11 or 1.12 API but I'm not sure. So if anyone has a solution to give the player the lapis, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`Dye dye = new Dye(); dye.setColor(DyeColor.BLUE); 
ItemStack lapis = dye.toItemStack();`

Answer (score 0):

1st variant

```
ItemStack yourInkSack = new ItemStack(Material.INK_SACK, 1, (short) 4);
```

2nd variant

```
ItemStack yourInkSack = new ItemStack(Material.INK_SACK);
yourInkSack.setDurability((short) 4);
```

Comment: I did not mean the block, I meant LAPIS the dye, its item ID is 351:4. It has a data value and I don't know how to add a data value to an item stack.

Comment: There is a method ItemStack.setDurability(data), where data is your 4.

Comment: Have you tried ItemStack item = new ItemStack(Material.INK_SACK): item.setDurability(4); ? What's the problem with that?